# Usage of the word halt

Tags: british-english

I was looking for the meaning of Draw up and this was the definition:" to cause to a halt". The thing is it confused me more because I have no idea what halt means and in what sentences could I use It. Thank you I'll be looking forward for your answers!

Comment: "to cause to a halt" doesn't make sense; are you sure the definition wasn't "to cause to halt," or perhaps "to bring to a halt"?

Comment: A dictionary should probably be your first source.

Answer (score 1):

*Halt*, in this sense, is an exact synonym of *stop*; you can mentally replace *halt* with *stop* to understand the definition.

Comment: What other uses could halt have? thank you for your answer!

Comment: There are several other definitions of *halt* as a verb, adjective, or noun. [Here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halt) is a list of definitions in an American English online dictionary.